# Factorial program is not working properly in C WHY?

Tags: c

I'm new to c programing I made a program of factorial but it doesn't working properly.I'm adding the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    int x=1;
    int z,n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(z=1;z<=n;z++)
    {
        x=x*z;
    }
    printf("%d",&x);
    getch();
 }
```

Comment: As a beginner it helps to remember:

scanf(&x)
printf(x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `printf("%d", x)` instead of `printf("%d", &x)`.

Answer (score 4):

These are the corrections you must make in your program

> 1. It's `printf("%d", x)` not `printf("%d", &x)`
> 2. Avoid using `#include<conio.h>`, it is depreciated.
> 3. It's good practice to use  `int main()` instead of `void main()`,
>       and return a positive integer `0`, if all goes well.

Comment: @zeta it is #include <conio.h> , edit mistake

Answer (score 3):

As a unary operator `&x` will return the address of `x`, which has type `int*`. This can be interpreted as `int`, however, usually your compiler would give a warning when you try to print something with the wrong formatting flag (if you use GCC try `-Wall` as compiler option).

Since you don't want to print the address but the value of `x` just drop the unnecessary operand:

```
printf("%d", x);
```

Answer (score 0):

first, available space for an int its to small, your max value will be n=15

second,you dont need to use library `conio.h`

third, its not working because you're using `&x`, erase it and will work

forth, you can do the *for statement* in one line

fifth, change `void main()` to `int main()` and add `return 0;` at the end

sixth, this code will work for you

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=1;
    int z,n;
    scanf("%i",&n);
    for(z=1;z<=n;x*=z++,printf("value of z is =%i , value of  factorial is =%i\n",z,x));
    printf("%i",x);
    return 0;
 }
```